# Bootstrap 5.2.3 addEventListener does not work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have sample page and Bootstrap dialog is returned from server.
Then I want to display it inside DIV.

Once clicked, it gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: myModal.addEventListener is not a function

at this line:

```
myModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function () {
```

Why? Thanks!

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p><a href="#" onclick="showSubscriptionInfo();">Open dialog</p>
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
   </body>
   
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
   <script>
   function     showSubscriptionInfo(){
     var data = ''+
      '<div class="modal fade" id="subsModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">'+
      '  <div class="modal-dialog">'+
      '    <div class="modal-content" style="height:450px">'+
      '      <div class="modal-body">'+
               '<p>xxx</p>'+
      '      </div>'+
          '<div class="modal-footer">'+
          '  <button type="button" class="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
          '</div> '+
      '    </div>'+
      '  </div>'+
      '</div>';
    
     document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = data;
     var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('subsModal'));
     myModal.show();
     
     myModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function () {
       alert(1);
     }, { once: true });
     myModal.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function () {
       alert(2);
     }, { once: true });
     
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: you are referencing something that is not in the DOM when loaded. The modal should be there and hidden as in the Bootstrap example. then you have show.bs.modal to display it

Comment: FYI, you have content (script elements) outside the body and head elements. This is invalid HTML. Also, use buttons for actions, not anchors. They have distinct purposes, with anchors being for _navigation_. Then, [never link "click here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking), even for a demo.

Comment: Protip: Use console logs or breakpoints for debugging, not alerts. You'll waste much less of your life dismissing dialogs and the event is then persistent for later review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events used in bootstrap modals must be tracked on the div that was used to instantiate the modal (`document.getElementById('subsModal')`) and not on the bootstrap.Modal object (`new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('subsModal'))`).

See more in the [modal docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/) and [modal event docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#events).

```js
function showSubscriptionInfo() {
  var data = '' +
    '<div class="modal fade" id="subsModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">' +
    '  <div class="modal-dialog">' +
    '    <div class="modal-content" style="height:450px">' +
    '      <div class="modal-body">' +
    '<p>xxx</p>' +
    '      </div>' +
    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
    '  <button type="button" class="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' +
    '</div> ' +
    '    </div>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>';

  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = data;
  var subsModal = document.getElementById('subsModal');
  var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(subsModal);
  subsModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function() {
    alert(1);
  }, {
    once: true
  });
  subsModal.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    alert(2);
  }, {
    once: true
  });

  myModal.show();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Rx+T1VzGupg4BHQYs2gCW9It+akI2MM/mndMCy36UVfodzcJcF0GGLxZIzObiEfa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p><a href="#" onclick="showSubscriptionInfo();">Click HERE</a></p>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
<!-- script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script -->
</html>
```